# opentok Tokbox Broadcast HLS video remove black background color

Tags: php, opentok

I am integrating opentok broadcast using hls.

In the hls video, i need to remove black background color,

Please refer the attached screenshot

[image]

How can i remove this black color?

Answer (score 0):

Neither HLS/HTML5 Video nor the OpenTok SDK provide any means for manipulating the video.
If you want to limit the actual video to a certain area, you need to do that at the source.

What you can do in the browser is zoom and pan into your video by just treating the video element like any other HTML element and cleverly positioning it inside a smaller box.

If the black background is always in the same part of the video and not something dynamic, you can reduce the visible area of your video to the actual image size by putting the video tag inside of a block-level element of fixed size.

i.e.:

```
<div class="videobox"><video src="..." /></div>
```

Then go on and position the video element within your block element (div), so that the black parts will flow out of the div.

i.e. (your visible image is 625x465px centered at the top, the whole box is 1875x708):

```
.videobox {
  position: relative;
  width: 625px;
  height: 465px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.videobox video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 625px;
}
```

More details on how to zoom into a video and cut off excess parts can be found in this guide from Mozilla:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/

They demonstrate the cutoff in an example about rotating the video inside a stage area, but as this is just normal HTML+CSS, it applies in the same way to "just zooming/panning".